# Equivalent of Rebol effect [gradient] in Red?

Tags: rebol, red

I searched on Google but can't find any example in Red equivalent to this in Rebol:
http://www.rebol.com/view/demos/gradient.r

```
view layout [
    style box box 64x64
    across backdrop 0.50.0
    vh1 "Gradient Examples"
    below guide
    box effect [gradient]
    box yellow effect [gradient]
    box effect [gradient 200.0.0]
    box yellow effect [gradient 200.0.0]
    box effect [gradient 200.0.0 0.0.200]
    return
    box effect [gradient 1x0]
    box yellow effect [gradient 1x0]
    box effect [gradient 1x0 200.0.0]
    box yellow effect [gradient 1x0 200.0.0]
    box effect [gradient 1x0 200.0.0 0.0.200]
    return
    box effect [gradient -1x0]
    box yellow effect [gradient -1x0]
    box effect [gradient -1x0 200.0.0]
    box yellow effect [gradient -1x0 200.0.0]
    box effect [gradient -1x0 200.0.0 0.0.200]
    return
    box effect [gradient 0x1]
    box yellow effect [gradient 0x1]
    box effect [gradient 0x1 200.0.0]
    box yellow effect [gradient 0x1 200.0.0]
    box effect [gradient 0x1 200.0.0 0.0.200]
    return
    box effect [gradient 0x-1]
    box yellow effect [gradient 0x-1]
    box effect [gradient 0x-1 200.0.0]
    box yellow effect [gradient 0x-1 200.0.0]
    box effect [gradient 0x-1 200.0.0 0.0.200]
    return
    box effect [gradient 1x1]
    box yellow effect [gradient 1x1]
    box effect [gradient 1x1 200.0.0]
    box yellow effect [gradient 1x1 200.0.0]
    box effect [gradient 1x1 200.0.0 0.0.200]
    return
    box effect [gradient -1x1]
    box yellow effect [gradient -1x1]
    box effect [gradient -1x1 200.0.0]
    box yellow effect [gradient -1x1 200.0.0]
    box effect [gradient -1x1 200.0.0 0.0.200]
    return
    box effect [gradient 1x-1]
    box yellow effect [gradient 1x-1]
    box effect [gradient 1x-1 200.0.0]
    box yellow effect [gradient 1x-1 200.0.0]
    box effect [gradient 1x-1 200.0.0 0.0.200]
    return
    box effect [gradient -1x-1]
    box yellow effect [gradient -1x-1]
    box effect [gradient -1x-1 200.0.0]
    box yellow effect [gradient -1x-1 200.0.0]
    box effect [gradient -1x-1 200.0.0 0.0.200]
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Red's View doesn't support effect pipe yet, but you can set gradients in Draw:

```
view [base 100x100 draw [fill-pen linear 0.0.0 255.255.255 0x0 100x100 box 0x0 100x100]]
```

(I'm on Linux, so I can't test it, but it should work IMO).

See https://doc.red-lang.org/en/draw.html#_linear_gradient_fill for more information.